# Outlier detection for a multidimensional, multiclass dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers, supervised-learning

I have a dataset with more than 4000 instances with 125 features each instance, and 8 different classes. I tried to search for some already implemented outlier algorithms in Scikit Learn, but the problem is that they all work on single dimensional datasets and they don't take account of the classes. My doubts are:

1. Since I have 125 features per class, would it make sense to use an outlier detection algorithm that takes account of all the features (e.g.: if more than 10 features out of 125 are outliers, the whole instance is deleted)?
2. Since I have a multiclass dataset, would it make sense to use the outlier detection algorithm not for the whole dataset, but class per class? I mean: in my case would it make sense to split the dataset in 8 partitions (one for each class), and run the outlier detection algorithm independently for each partition?

I am also looking for some already implemented method, if someone could suggest me a library of perhaps some documentation.

Comment: This video is quite interesting, specially for multidimensional data https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/Rkc5x/anomaly-detection-vs-supervised-learning Maybe it could help you

Comment: Have you given a shot at (multinomial) logistic regression? You could identify outliers by look at the instances with large residuals.